How to use "color of colormap" to pick a color from a defined colormap for pgfplots \addplot color in a foreach loop?
This is my example:
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
pgfplotsset{
colormap={palette}{
color={red} 
color={green}
color={blue}
}}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}

\legend{red, green, blue}

\addplot[color of colormap={0 of palette}, mark=*] coordinates {(0, 1)};
\addplot[color of colormap={500 of palette}, mark=*] coordinates {(0,2)};
\addplot[color of colormap={1000 of palette}, mark=*] coordinates {(0,3)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}


I would like to omit the manual plot definition and turn it into a foreach loop like this:
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}

\legend{red, green, blue}

\foreach \x in {0,...,2}{%
\addplot[color of colormap={500*\x of palette}, mark=*] coordinates {(0,1+\x)};
}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}

However, the result is not what I expected:

Not sure why am I getting Missing { inserted message. What is probably the main problem is this message: Package pgfplots Error: Did not find a suitable input source pos in a 'of colormap' specification. Did you forget the 'source pos'? It can be given as 'colors of colormap=(source pos of name)' or 'of colormap=(source pos=...,..)'.
Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

@hpekristiansen I am sorry for the inconvenience. Edited according to your reply.

\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\pgfplotsset{
colormap={palette}{
color={red} 
color={green}
color={blue}
}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\legend{red, green, blue}
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,...,2}{
\addplot[color of colormap={500*#1 of palette}, mark=*] coordinates {(0,1+#1)};
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Many thanks! Would you please explain to me why the classic foreach is not working?

The explanation is complicated and I am not able to account for the details. The inside of axis is run more than once to find limits and only drawn the last time - macros will then only have the very last value. Therefore there are special commands - see "8.1 Utility Commands" in the manual.

Thank you! Helped me a lot!
